# Disable auto sorting on property grid in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, propertygrid

I am dealing with property grid. I want to prevent auto sorting of column names for property grid.
here is my code. Bold highlighted code is my source for property grid and its order is just like I want to see. But Ext is auto sorting column orders alphabeticly. How can I prevent that.

Thanks for any suggestion.

```
Ext.ns('Application.propertygrid');
Application.propertygrid.FileDetail = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.PropertyGrid, {
    title: 'File Detail',
    height: 200,
    border: false,
    stripeRows: true,
    flex: 1,
    initComponent: function () {
        Application.propertygrid.FileDetail.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    source: {
        Name: 'Please select a file',
        Type: 'Please select a file',
        Size: 'Please select a file',
        Path: 'Please select a file',
        FullPath: 'Please select a file',
        Width: 'Please select a file',
        Height: 'Please select a file'
    },
    listeners: {
        beforeedit: function(){
            return false; // prevent editing 
        },
        headerclick: function(){
            return false; // prevent column sorting on click
        }
    }
})
Ext.reg('filedetail', Application.propertygrid.FileDetail);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah. I've done with it. And here is the solution.

```
var p = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
  ...
  // do not specify 'source' here
});

delete p.getStore().sortInfo; // Remove default sorting
p.getColumnModel().getColumnById('name').sortable = false; // set sorting of first column to false
p.setSource(source); // Now load data
```

Comment: User may still want to sort the columns but just wants to disable the auto sorting done on rendering.

Answer (score 7):

This will not work for the Extjs 4:

```
delete p.getStore().sortInfo; // Remove default sorting
p.getColumnModel().getColumnById('name').sortable = false; // set sorting of first column to false
p.setSource(source); // Now load data
```

You can try this:

```
p.getStore().sorters.items = [] // which should remove sorting information from the store
p.setSource(source) // now load the data
```

Answer (score 2):

For Extjs 3.4 should only need:

```
delete propertygrid.getStore().sortInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do this:
When I define my columns I set the `sortable property to false` and I define my own 'sortable flag', like this:

```
var column = {
            xtype: 'column-component',
            ...
            sortable: false,
            sortableColumn: true
        }
```

Later when a user clicks on the column header (the `headerclick` event gets triggered) and I check if the column is sortable or not, like this:

```
onHeaderClick: function(ct, column, e) {
    if (column.sortableColumn) {
        // do your own sorting ... 
    }
}
```