# ExtJs GroupingView prevent sorting of the group title

Tags: extjs

How to prevent sorting of the group title in GroupingView. By default group titles are sorted 'ASC'. I have a situation where "Adhoc Reports" group should order last in the GroupingView.

I need the group title to be in the following order

groupName: 'Federal Reports'
groupName: 'State Reports'
groupName: 'Ad Hoc Reports'

This is how these are grouped in the JSON.

Comment: Did you ever find your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Try to turn on `remoteSort` on your store.

**EDIT**

Additionally try to set `groupOnSort` to `false` and `remoteGroup` to `true`.

Comment: No Luck using remoteSort. My JSON data does not load remotely. {
 rows: [{
  groupName: 'Federal Reports',
  id: 'F_FICA',
  title: 'EEs with Medicare/OASDI ? No Withholding',
  description: 'Identifies any employees'
 },{
  groupName: 'Federal Reports',
  title: 'OASDI Taxes ? No Wages',
  description: 'Compares Federal Unemployment'
 },{
  groupName: 'State Reports',
  title: 'Fica EE and ER Wages',
  description: 'List any employees'
 },{
  groupName: 'Ad Hoc Reports',
  title: 'Negative Earnings',
  description: 'List of any '
 }]
}

Comment: I guess, group titles (groupName) are sorted first for grouping reason so that fields are assembled in those groups together. Is there a way to specify sortType for the groups?

Comment: Still no luck - groupOnSort to false and remoteGroup to true

Comment: OK - then we should have a look at your code. Please post a code snippet that is as concise as possible but replicates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, honestly I could not read your post carefully, but this maybe help you. Btw, I deal an issue like that on Ext PropertGrid, and it was a headache. [Disable auto sorting on property grid in ExtJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349804/disable-auto-sorting-on-property-grid-in-extjs)

Comment: Sorting attributes that are defined in the API, works fine for fields under each groups. But Groups itself does not have sorting feature. Either, I am missing something or may not be possible to define sort order for the group

Answer (score 0):

So I set `remoteGroup: true` and in my server side sorted data via SQL.

Similar issue was described here:
[Sorting the Grouped data in GridPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507005/sorting-the-grouped-data-in-gridpanel-of-extjs-by-group-sort-order)